# What is the connection between regularity structure and rough path theory?

Tags: stochastic-processes, soft-question, definition, stochastic-differential-equations

This refers to the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path where it mentions about rough path and regularity structure as explains in the page:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_structure It is understandable that regularity structure uses some concepts of rough path theory. I feel that rough path is like a one kind of regularity structure and there are more other structures. Is this correct? Can anyone write a bit to show the clear connection between the  rough path and regularity structure?

Comment: See section 13.2.2 and 13.3.2 in the notes of Martin Hairer and Peter Friz [here](http://hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf) detailing how to fit $\alpha$-Holder controlled rough paths into the context of regularity structures (the rough path structure and model)

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you so much.

Comment: @OP I am studying rough path theory and it is in itself a hard enough topic. If you already went through it and know how to answer your own question, would you mind answering it :)? cheers. In the meantime, if one day I am good enough to answer it, I will!

Comment: @MarineGalantin, My background is not mathematics but Engineering. I am trying to learn this topic to see if I can use it in signal processing ( it may not be possible). If my answer is obvious and not useful, I am sorry.

Comment: @Creater actually it is possible to use it in signal processing! I have done an application of rough paths on signal processing and stochastic filtering.

Comment: @MarineGalantin wow, I am seriously suprised and happy to know that someone else is also working in the same area. I searched google to see if anyone is working on it, but never found any reference. I am interested to know more, if it is fine with you.

Comment: I think the connection between rough paths and regularity structures is not fleshed out in Friz-Hairer. This article exposes in details the regularity structure on -controlled- rough paths: https://hal.science/hal-01661277v2/file/solve_rde_rg_revise.pdf . The author, Antoine Brault, also constructs modeled distributions, defined using regularity structures, and explains how to solve with those a sort of stochastic differential equation -called "rough"- more general than can be solved by Îto's method.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering it only to accept the request from @Marine Galantin. My answer may be completely wrong or too simple and obvious and useless, if so my sincere apology.

Rough path theory and regularity structure has one common theme i.e  'model'. A model which can replace the derivatives and coefficients of Taylor series. Taylor series or Taylor polynomial is fine for continously differentiable function but if the function is continuous but non-differentiable (like brownian motion) what can we do. To fix this problem we need a model which has the properties of Taylor series. To do so, few new "objects" were needed to be created. The "signature" of the rough path theory is a model of the regularity structure. The justfication and bound of those new "objects" are developed and called: a) Rough path theory for function which are solution to SDE and b) Regularity structure for function solution to SPDE.